# Converting cUrl PHP code to coldfusion

Tags: php, curl, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfhttp

I'm trying to convert some PHP code into ColdFusion and having issues in the curl method.

**PHP**:

```
  // Password
    $clientSecret = urlencode(settings::$password);
    // Information about the resource we need access for which in this case is graph.
    $graphId = 'https://graph.windows.net';
    $protectedResourceHostName = 'graph.windows.net';
    $graphPrincipalId = urlencode($graphId);
    // Information about the app
    $clientPrincipalId = urlencode($appPrincipalId);

    // Construct the body for the STS request
    $authenticationRequestBody = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret='.$clientSecret
              .'&'.'resource='.$graphPrincipalId.'&'.'client_id='.$clientPrincipalId;

    //Using curl to post the information to STS and get back the authentication response    
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set url 
    $stsUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/'.$appTenantDomainName.'/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stsUrl); 
    // Get the response back as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    // Mark as Post request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    // Set the parameters for the request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $authenticationRequestBody);

    // By default, HTTPS does not work with curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // read the output from the post request
    $output = curl_exec($ch);         
    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

**ColdFusion** Code:

```
    <cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="POST" result="resultName">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="grant_type" value="client_credentials">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="client_secret" value="#clientSecret#">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="resource" value="#graphPrincipalId#">
        <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="client_id" value="#clientPrincipalId#">
   </cfhttp>
```

When running the cfhttp call, I'm getting the `400 Bad Request` error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you setting `authenticationRequestBody`? Can you add that in your post? Also, for adding data to request body type must be `body`.

Comment: @Beginner : Added more details. So you reckon httpparams need to be of type `body` instead of `formfied`?

Comment: `httpparams need to be of type body instead of formfied?` You were trying to add data to request body. So it should be `body` and you need to manually set `content-type` header for that. Docs :[cfhttpparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something?

1. For adding data to the `body` of a `HTTP` request, you need to set `type` of [`cfhttpparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html) to `body`.
2. You need to manually set the `Content-Type` header for the type of content in body.

So, you can try this:

```
<!--- Set defaults  --->
<cfset requestBody = "">
<cfset stsUrl = "https://login.windows.net/#appTenantDomainName#/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0">

<!--- Set Data Variables --->
<cfset data["grant_type"] = "client_credentials">
<cfset data["client_secret"] = clientSecret>
<cfset data["resource"] = graphPrincipalId>
<cfset data["client_id"] = clientPrincipalId>

<!--- Request Body --->
<cfloop collection="#data#" item="key">
    <cfset requestBody &= key & "=" & data[key] & "&">
</cfloop>
<cfset requestBody = reReplace(requestBody, "&$", "", "1")>

<!--- Request --->
<cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="POST" result="resultName">       
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#requestBody#">
</cfhttp>
```

> **Not related to the question :** You must properly scope your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Beginner for guiding me through. The following solution worked:

```
<cfset authenticationRequestBody = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret=#clientSecret#&resource=#graphPrincipalId#&client_id=#clientPrincipalId#">
<cfset stsUrl = "https://login.windows.net/#appTenantDomainName#/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0">
<cfhttp url="#stsUrl#" method="POST" result="resultName">       
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#authenticationRequestBody#">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the working code. However, if @Beginner provided the solution, it might be a nice gesture to ask them to promote their comment to an official "answer" (and mark it as the solution) as a thanks for helping out :-)

Comment: @Leigh : Beginner can still post his comment as an answer. I have already upvoted his comment and mentioned him in my working solution.

Comment: {does best Bob Barker impression}  *@Beginner Come on down...* ;-)